# Remove an element from a vector by value - C++

Tags: c++, vector

If I have

```
vector<T> list
```

Where each element in the list is unique, what's the easiest way of deleting an element provided that I don't know if it's in the list or not? I don't know the index of the element and I don't care if it's not on the list.

Comment: Why the name of a `vector` container is `list` .. It could be confusing, a lot (for someone, that reads your code)

Comment: @KirilKirov, I don't think list is a reserved keyword in C++? Even so, it's just an example.

Comment: It is a container type, just as `vector` is. And both are pretty different :)

Comment: is this a homework question or are you trying to solve a specific problem? if the latter describing the problem may give you alternative solutions, if the former you should tag it as homework

Comment: If all elements in your container must be unique and you don't need to use its index, you probably should use std::set<T> instead of vector.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use the [Erase-remove idiom for std::vector](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove)

Quote:

```
std::vector<int> v; 
// fill it up somehow
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 99), v.end()); 
// really remove all elements with value 99
```

---

Or, if you're sure, that it is unique, just iterate through the vector and erase the found element. Something like:

```
for( std::vector<T>::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter )
{
    if( *iter == VALUE )
    {
        v.erase( iter );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would note that you can use find_if() instead of straight iterations.

Comment: Your 2nd answer .. I wouldn't do it this way.  To extend to delete ALL occurrences of VALUE would trip people up in 2 possible places:  `iter` is invalidated after `.erase()`, and `++iter` would fail immediately.  Would have to write `iter=v.erase(iter);` instead. Now if you do it that way, an extra `++iter` will be committed after an erasure, skipping elements.  To fix this you should always iterate __backwards__ through the `vector` when deleting elements.  Using a numerical index will fix these problems. `for( int i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; i-- ) if( v[i]==VALUE ) v.erase( v.begin()+i ) ;`

Comment: I know, but I said "to extend to delete"

Comment: @bobobobo - true, but this is another answer, does not make my answer wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Kiril's answer, you can use this function in your code :

```
template<typename T>
inline void remove(vector<T> & v, const T & item)
{
    v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), item), v.end());
}
```

And use it like this

```
remove(myVector, anItem);
```

Answer (score 3):

**If occurrences are unique, then you should be using `std::set<T>`, not `std::vector<T>`.**

This has the added benefit of an `erase` member function, which does what you want.

See how using the correct container for the job provides you with more expressive tools?

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::set<int> notAList{1,2,3,4,5};

   for (auto el : notAList)
      std::cout << el << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';

   notAList.erase(4);

   for (auto el : notAList)
      std::cout << el << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}

// 1 2 3 4 5
// 1 2 3 5
```

### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0281f4faecfc466b)

Comment: A vector is used for a reason, e.g. preserving the insert order. so `If occurrences are unique, then you should be using std::set<T>, not std::vector<T>` is nowhere valid. Let's just focus on the OP's settings.

Answer (score 1):

From c++20

```
//LIKE YOU MENTIONED EACH ELEMENT IS UNIQUE
std::vector<int> v = { 2,4,6,8,10 };

//C++20 UNIFORM ERASE FUNCTION (REMOVE_ERASE IDIOM IN ONE FUNCTION)
std::erase(v, 8); //REMOVES 8 FROM VECTOR
```

Now try

```
std::erase(v, 12);
```

Nothing will happen, the vector remains intact.